# PyInstaller fails to correctly package ruamel.yaml

Tags: pyinstaller, ruamel.yaml

I'm unable to package ruamel.yaml using PyInstaller.

I've used the following simple test case:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
parser = YAML(typ="safe", pure=True)
print(parser.load("17"))
```

This works fine when run normally, but produces this exception after being packaged with PyInstaller:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'YAML' from 'ruamel.yaml' (/tmp/_MEIsScRyt/ruamel/yaml/__init__.pyc)
```

I can partially work around this problem by referring to `YAML` as `ruamel.yaml.main.YAML`, but various properties are referred to via `ruamel.yaml` inside the library, and I can't change those.

How can I ensure PyInstaller correctly packages the entire ruamel.yaml package?

I'm using the latest PyInstaller version as installed via pip3, `4.2.dev0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can refer to `ruamel.yaml.main.YAML` but not to `ruamel.yaml.YAML` it looks like pyinstaller doesn't correctly install `ruamel.yaml`'s `__init__.py` as that does:

```
from ruamel.yaml.main import *
```

You should check to see if that file is available under subdir `ruamel/yaml`.

In general you should compare the file hierarchy that PyInstaller produces/stores with the the result of how `ruamel.yaml **should** be installed, [as specified in the documentation](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html):

```
pip install ruamel.yaml
```

There are some corrections in the `setup.py` of all `ruamel.*` and `ruamel.*.*` packages to deal with correctly installing these nested namespaced packages. This however is only adjusted for, and tested using, `pip`. Installers that are not 100% compatible with `pip` might make assumptions that are not valid and fail to install correctly.